# Wordpress: htaccess redirect from subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, xampp

I have a base .htaccess rules on xampp localhost project

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/project.ru/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /www/project.ru/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If I I fill this path - www/project.ru/popular/ I want that redirected me to popular.php in main theme and it allow access 
Now I receive "404 Page not found"

How make it?

Comment: What is the exact url you want as a result? (rewrite **/www/project.ru/popular/** to what?)

Comment: **poncha**, as a result I want to have /www/project.ru/popular.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try turning on multiviews:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

which will kick in mod_negotiation and will attempt to fuzzy match requests to resources. So `/foo/` would load `/foo.php`.

Comment: Note, however, that mixing `mod_rewrite` and `MultiViews` may result in unexpected behavior. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602330/mod-rewrite-issue

Comment: I'm not understand what you mean. 

I want to create exactly the same as http://techcrunch.com/ 
tabs latest | popular

Comment: @Constantine it does this: **"If I I fill this path - www/project.ru/popular/ I want that redirected me to popular.php"**