# .htaccess not working properly on ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, ubuntu-12.04

```
RewriteRule    ^profile?$    profile.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^profile/?$    profile.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$    profile.php?profile_id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule    ^profile/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/?$    profile.php?profile_id=$1&p=$2    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule    ^profile/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/?$    profile.php?profile_id=$1&p=$2&id=$3    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]+)/?$    index.php?p=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

When I open

```
{url}/profile/{profile_id}
```

the request is going to profile.php but profile_id is not accessible via $_REQUEST['profile_id'].
All other requests are working properly.

Can anyone help what can be the possible reason?

Comment: Perhaps this is because the URL is matching one of the first two rules and because you have marked them with the [`[L]` flag (LAST)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l), no other rules are checked and the user is simply routed to `profile.php`.

Comment: I tried changing the order and removing [L] flag but didn't worked. Same .htaccess was working on previous ubuntu server(same configuration) but when I moved it to a new server it is not working.

Comment: I just tested your htaccess on this URL http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, works fine. You're sure the rewrite engine is enabled?
Just to be sure, can you add 'RewriteEngine On' at the top of your htaccess

Comment: I am confused as it was working on my previous server. Rewrite engine is on and RewriteEngine On is already added on the top of .htaccess. I followed instruction at http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache to enable mod rewrite

Comment: what about [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) option, ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602330/mod-rewrite-issue, try to disable it

Comment: Thanks a lot man..it was due to multiviews..I disabled it from /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and it worked :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling the [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) option as per [@ValdimirDimitrov's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568144/htaccess-not-working-properly-on-ubuntu-server#comment49216751_30568144).